# Passport comparison between Germany and Canada.

Tags: visa, passport

The [Henley and Partners Visa free index 2018](https://www.henleyglobal.com/henley-passport-index/) lists the German passport as the most powerful in the world with a visa free access to 177 countries. My wife holds a Canadian passport and she is eligible to travel to 172 countries visa free. A US passport holder can travel to 173 countries visa free which is one more than Canada. We are curious as to which are these 5 countries which provide visa free access to Germans but not to Canadians and the one country which provides visa free access to US citizens and not to Canadians. Kindly elaborate.

Comment: It may be true that Canada is good for 172, and US is good for 173, but they're not the *same* 172 countries. For example, US citizens need a visa in advance for Turkey and Venezuela but Canadians do not. You can compare [Visa requirements for Canadian citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Canadian_citizens) and [Visa requirements for United States citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_United_States_citizens). And of course, [Visa requirements for German citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_German_citizens).

Comment: @GregHewgill Hasn't the US-Turkey visa friction subsided?  Also, the charge for Canadians to enter Turkey has historically been much higher than for US citizens.

Comment: @phoog: I don't know whether the friction has subsided, I'm just looking at the Wikipedia articles which are usually pretty up to date but are not definitive. Things change all the time, of course. The summary is that things are not anywhere near as simple as the OP presumes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brazil, Iran, Vietnam, according to [this site](https://www.passportindex.org/comparebyPassport.php?p1=de&p2=ca&fl=&s=yes). They seem to calculate differently, as the numbers differ (161/158).